# ZFS write performance slow after scrub

Tags: performance, nas, storage, zfs

My ZFS pool consists of 4 mirrors with 2 disks each (4TB, 6TB, 6TB, 6TB) and just recently one of the 6TB mirrors went into a degraded state which was fixed by using the scrub command (`zpool scrub global-pool`).

Now `zpool status -v` shows the following, indicating that the pool has recovered:

```
pool: global-pool
state: ONLINE
scan: scrub repaired 34.9M in 21:10:22 with 0 errors on Thu Aug 18 19:41:16 2022
config:

        NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        global-pool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-11SPEB0_WD-WCC4E0039950  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-00SPEB0_WD-WCC4E7PA2Y76  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-2                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST6000DM003-2CY186_WCT10EQQ           ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST6000DM003-2CY186_WCT295YM           ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-3                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            hdd-6000gb-006                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            hdd-6000gb-007                            ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-4                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
            hdd-6000gb-004                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            hdd-6000gb-005                            ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Before this happened, my write speeds were at around 130 MB/s and now can't exceed 15 MB/s which is **not** acceptable.

What is the reason for this decrease in write speed?

Could this be caused by the scrub command or is there still an error that is not shown via the status command?

Another possible reason could be that either the entire pool is getting full or that two of the 4 mirrors are nearly full.

Output of `zpool list -v`:

```
NAME                                           SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
global-pool                                   20.0T  12.8T  7.21T        -         -     1%    63%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  mirror                                      3.62T  3.40T   230G        -         -     3%  93.8%      -    ONLINE
    ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-11SPEB0_WD-WCC4E0039950      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    ata-WDC_WD40EZRX-00SPEB0_WD-WCC4E7PA2Y76      -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  mirror                                      5.45T  4.75T   720G        -         -     3%  87.1%      -    ONLINE
    ata-ST6000DM003-2CY186_WCT10EQQ               -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    ata-ST6000DM003-2CY186_WCT295YM               -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  mirror                                      5.45T  3.07T  2.39T        -         -     0%  56.2%      -    ONLINE
    hdd-6000gb-006                                -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    hdd-6000gb-007                                -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
  mirror                                      5.45T  1.56T  3.89T        -         -     0%  28.6%      -    ONLINE
    hdd-6000gb-004                                -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    hdd-6000gb-005                                -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
```

Thank you for your help!
If you need more information please tell me and I will provide it.